# How do I prepare for installing Ubuntu from Windows (Wubi)?

Tags: installation, windows, wubi

If I were to install Ubuntu via the method stated here; http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Will I need to download/install anything else first? Do I simply select "Boot Ubuntu" and then go about my business? Will my HDD need partitioning beforehand? If I save files while running Ubuntu where do they go when I decide to boot Windows instead?

Just trying to figure out the best way to use Ubuntu without removing the Windows OS (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Will I need to download/install anything else first?*

No. But once you run the installer, it will download approximately 500 MB of data.

> *Do I simply select "Boot Ubuntu" and then go about my business?*

Yes, Windows Boot Menu will give you an option to do that when you start up.

> *Will my HDD need partitioning beforehand?*

No.

> *If I save files while running Ubuntu where do they go when I decide to boot Windows instead?*

They stay on the Ubuntu "disk" (which is actually a large file on your Windows drive); if you wish to "share" them it's easiest to use a USB flash drive or similar. Alternatively, set up a FAT32 partition which both operating systems can access, but that may be getting too complicated...

Comment: Thank you so much, that's all I needed to hear! Time to run the installer (:

Comment: Actually one more question, which "Installation size" do I pick? It defaults to 18GB, is this necessary?

Comment: I'd recommend a minimum of 10GB, and the default is a good balance if you intend to try/use Ubuntu actively.

Comment: I've got about 60GB free so I'll go with the default 18GB then.

Comment: Sounds good... :)